# Why ofstream does not write utf16 on linux in binary mode?

Tags: c++, linux, utf-16, ofstream, c++03

On Linux, I'm having some trouble writing UTF-16 to file using ofstream class while the same code work perfectly fine on Windows. Below is the sample code

```
MyString content;
content = L"hello\r\n";
const short unsigned int* output = content.asUnicodeType<MyString::UTF16>().c_str();
ofstream outFile("test.txt", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
outFile.write((char *)output, content.size() * sizeof(MyString::UTF16));
//outFile.write((char *)content.c_str(), content.size() * sizeof(wchar_t));
outFile.close();
return 0;
```

I have confirmed that output is correctly converted to UTF-16 format

```
(gdb) x /16b output
0x61a288:       104     0       101     0       108     0       108     0
0x61a290:       111     0       13      0       10      0       0       0
```

However, after it finish and I tried to open the file. It look like the content is being written as UTF8 despite the fact that i'm asking it to write in binary mode

If I switch and write it as wide character, then the content is correct written as UTF32 on Linux.

Any suggestion would be great!

PS: due to platform restriction, I can't use C++ 11 standard

Thanks

Comment: It's just a class that wrap around wchar_t string. It doesn't really matter right as I'm writing the content of output

Comment: What does `od -t x1 test.txt` give you?

Comment: thank you for reminding me of this. I was opening the file on Windows and because I missed the BOM, it read the content as ansi.. after adding the BOM.. it's all good now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually written the content as UTF-16 but because I missed the BOM, the file opening on Windows didn't recognize it so I thought that it written the content as UTF8

Answer (score 1):

If `content.asUnicodeType<MyString::UTF16>()` returns a `std::string` then you have undefined behaviour. `.c_str()` returns a c-string owned by the `std::string`, but in your case the `std::string` is a temporary object, which results in its c-string being deleted imidiately.

To fix this, you must keep the `std::string` around as long as you need the c-string:

```
auto output_s = content.asUnicodeType<MyString::UTF16>();
const short unsigned int* output = output_s.c_str();
```

I don't know if this will fix your problems, but is is a good idea to fix undefined behaviours anyhow.

Oh, and by the way, try to use utf8 everywhere, especially when reading and writing files. No matter how much effort you spend to get utf16 right, you are probably doing it wrong.
See http://utf8everywhere.org